# Drawing a 5 cards with bias from Bernoulli distribution in python

Tags: python, statistics

i need to implement 100 repetitions of drawing 5  Bernoulli random variable (5 cards)with bias 0.2 in python and plot the distribution.

so far my implementation is

```
 for i in range(5):
       b= bernoulli.rvs(p=0.2,size=100)
```

how ever Bernoulli.rvs generates 100 repetitions with 0.2 bias.this is suitable for drawing a single card. how do i implement for drawing 5 cards.?i added a for loop in my implementation. but im not sure if its right.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
Tutorials are readily available for plotting and handling parallel data; where is the rest of your coding attempt?  What is your question on that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved
i solved it by using np.random.binomial rather than using bernoulli.rvs. it solved my problem.